# Karate UI automation: Not identify locator when calling test case of other feature file and storing feature file variable in other feature file

Tags: testing, web, automated-tests, karate, e2e-testing

- def storeInfo = call read('classpath:com/features/appABCTest.feature@CreateStore')
- def storeName = createStore.storeLocation
- waitFor('#loc')
- click('#loc')

If I am using * call read('classpath:com/features/appABCTest.feature@CreateStore') directly without storing in variable , able to identify locator and perform operation.

please help.

I am trying to perform end to end automation. As for example: calling testcase of other feature file in different feature , storing in a variable and get the value of variable to use in different test case to perform e2e testing.

Comment: sorry can't make out anything. follow this process: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue